# Piwik Events API - How to Query Single Action

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, matomo

I setup a custom trackEvent using this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Like', '<?php echo $id ?>']);">Like Me</a>
```

So "Like" is the category, and "$id" is the action, which will be different depending on which page is being viewed.

This works fine and successfully get the custom event into my Piwik dashboard under the "Like" category. For example, I clicked on this link on 3 different pages so I have 10, 11, and 12 as actions in my dashboard.

To query them, I'm using this URL in a HTTP request:

```
http://www.MYPIWIKURL.com/?module=API&method=Events.getAction&idSite=1&period=day&date=today&format=JSON&token_auth=MYAUTHTOKEN
```

This returns an array with all 3 of the actions listed as nested arrays. I'm wondering, however, how I can return *only* the array with the action I want to view? For example, action 10?

I tried adding "e_a=10", "action_name=10", and "segment=actions==10" to the URL, but they aren't recognized.

Could someone point me in the right direction for querying a single action within a category? Seems like I'm almost there!

Also--I *do* know that I could loop through the array and get the action I want, but eventually there will be thousands of actions, so that wouldn't be very efficient I don't think.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An actually better solution here is to use the API parameter `&label=10` which will return the row where the label is `10`. This parameter works in all APIs and lets you easily filter and keep only one row. Learn more: http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/reference

Using Segments is not recommended because it will trigger archiving of data for this segment, because segment data is not pre-processed. However using the &label= parameter will be very fast.

Comment: Pro! Thanks a lot--definitely notice the faster load. Accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong segment identifier. For anyone who may have this same issue, the segment to use is:

```
segment=eventAction==10
```

So the full URL would be:

http://www.MYPIWIKURL.com/?module=API&method=Events.getAction**&segment=eventAction==10**&idSite=1&period=day&date=today&format=JSON&token_auth=MYAUTHTOKEN

Comment: Almost 6 years later this was the exact answer for me